# Unable to receive click on menu items in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm having a ToolBar made as ActionBar in a Fragment. I'm able to add ActionBar menu items but I'm not able to receive click response when I click on any ActionBar menu item.

I have read a lot of similar questions, I tried all but I'm still facing issue, so asked a question here.

**The Fragment**

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_detail, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mToolBar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.tb_toolbar); 

        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
        mToolBar.setTitle(R.string.project_details);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.project_detail_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.options:
                // do something
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In my case in code above, **onOptionsItemSelected** is not even getting called. 
Any pointers why ?

**The Activity where I'm inflating this Fragment -**

```
public class TestJust extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_just);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, new ProjectDetailFragment());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

**project_detail_menu.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/options"
        android:title="options"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: check my update answer

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Hopefully it should now work. Tested in Mac Air

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your problem is that you're always returning `true` from the ***activity's `onOptionsItemSelected`*** method.

When you return `true`, you consume the click event inside the method in the activity, that's why the click event never reaches the `onOptionsItemSelected` method inside your fragment.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear()   
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.project_detail_menu, menu);
    }


   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.options:
            // do something
              return true;
        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: i have added activity and menu project_detail_menu.xml code in question

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You are calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in onCreateView()

Please call that method in onCreate()

Like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Calling this method in onCreate() ensures that the menu must participate in Fragment.

Then,

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu_items, menu);
}
```

Finally,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.options:
            // do something
            break;
    }
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

It should work now.

Comment: still now working. i have added activity and menu project_detail_menu.xml code in question

Answer (score 0):

initialize option in `onCreateOptionMenu` then check it. you only inflate menu, use without initialize option, first initialize then use it.

like: `MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.option);`

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater); 
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.option);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.options:
            // do something
            return true;//<- Here you need to return true because breaking compile from this line returns default false;
         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

Comment: why copy answer my

Comment: do you think while you typing i can copy your answer? check time bro

Comment: please update your question with project_detail_menu.xml add this

Comment: i have added activity and menu project_detail_menu.xml  code in question